# What is the recommended lifespan of an AWS client in the .net SDK?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

For example, working with the `AmazonSQSClient` in a web or otherwise multi-threaded application:

How many instances should exist at any moment?

Should I ever dispose of it and create a new one?

Do I need to prevent multiple instances from being created?

Answer (score 6):

All Client instances are threadsafe in the .NET SDK. Therefore you could potentially reuse a single client across your application if the state of that client meets the needs of all threads. The clients are also very light-weight so instantiating and disposing of them will incur little overhead and is a valid usage option as well.

`AmazonSQSClient` is an example where you might want multiple Clients using long polling to maximize performance, but you'd incur some additional cost so you'd want to balance these concerns for your app.

The only reason I can think of where it would be imperative to dispose of and re-initialize a Client instance would be to prevent a memory leak and release references. I don't have enough experience with the .NET SDK to speak to this but I haven't had issues with memory leaks introduced by the AWS SDK classes in Java and the implementation design seems to be similar.